# Como enviar un objeto a un namespace(una clase de tipo interfaz grafica) y setear el objeto para ser usado por acciones de botones C++

Tags: c++, .net, socket, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que posee un dos administradores conectados a un servidor por medio de `sockets` e hilos. Incluye interfaz gráfica. El problema surge cuando deseo enviar los objetos de tipo `socketC` a la interfaz para que cada interfaz envíe datos al `socket` del servidor pero no encuentro forma de setearlos en la interfaz. 
Código del administrador que crea los objetos `sockets` y los envía a la interfaz

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace std;
using namespace AdministradorS;

struct arg_struct {
    SOCKET socket;
    int puerto;
    string ip;
};


void* crearSocketCliente(void *datosRec) {
    struct arg_struct *datos = (struct arg_struct *)datosRec;
    socketC sCliente1(datos->puerto, datos->ip, datos->socket);
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    AdministradorS::loginAdmi loginAdmi_sec(sCliente1);
    loginAdmi_sec.ShowDialog();

    return NULL;
}


void main()
{
string ipAddress = "192.168.0.6";           // IP Address of the server
int port1 = 5400;                       // Listening port # on the server
int port2 = 5500;
SOCKET SocketAdministrador1 = NULL;
SOCKET SocketAdministrador2 = NULL;
struct arg_struct datosAdministrador1;
struct arg_struct datosAdministrador2;
datosAdministrador1.socket = SocketAdministrador1;
datosAdministrador1.puerto = port1;
datosAdministrador1.ip = ipAddress;
datosAdministrador2.socket = SocketAdministrador2;
datosAdministrador2.puerto = port2;
datosAdministrador2.ip = ipAddress;


pthread_t thread1, thread2;
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &crearSocketCliente, (void *)&datosAdministrador1);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &crearSocketCliente, (void *)&datosAdministrador2);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);


// Gracefully close down everything
closesocket(SocketAdministrador1);
closesocket(SocketAdministrador2);
WSACleanup();
}
```

Código de una ventana de la interfaz(la de logearse el administrador) que recibe el objeto, intente con una variable `static` pero setea un solo objeto por lo tanto las dos interfaces creadas manejan el mismo `socket`

```
namespace AdministradorS {
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
/// <summary>
/// Resumen de loginAdmi
/// </summary>
public ref class loginAdmi : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{



public:

    loginAdmi(socketC sock)
    {
        //definir el objeto de tipo socket pero en donde?
        InitializeComponent(sock);


        //
        //TODO: agregar código de constructor aquí
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Limpiar los recursos que se estén usando.
    /// </summary>
    ~loginAdmi()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnAceptar;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtPassw;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtUsuario;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Variable del diseñador necesaria.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Método necesario para admitir el Diseñador. No se puede modificar
    /// el contenido de este método con el editor de código.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(socketC sock)
    {
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->btnAceptar = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->txtPassw = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->txtUsuario = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Lucida Calligraphy", 27.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(309, 164);
        this->label1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(236, 72);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 7;
        this->label1->Text = L"LOGIN";
        // 
        // btnAceptar
        // 
        this->btnAceptar->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->btnAceptar->Location = System::Drawing::Point(269, 542);
        this->btnAceptar->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this->btnAceptar->Name = L"btnAceptar";
        this->btnAceptar->Size = System::Drawing::Size(276, 55);
        this->btnAceptar->TabIndex = 6;
        this->btnAceptar->Text = L"Aceptar";
        this->btnAceptar->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btnAceptar->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &loginAdmi::btnAceptar_Click);

        // 
        // txtPassw
        // 
        this->txtPassw->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Times New Roman", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->txtPassw->Location = System::Drawing::Point(212, 398);
        this->txtPassw->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this->txtPassw->Name = L"txtPassw";
        this->txtPassw->PasswordChar = '*';
        this->txtPassw->Size = System::Drawing::Size(424, 49);
        this->txtPassw->TabIndex = 5;
        this->txtPassw->Text = L"PASSWORD";
        this->txtPassw->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Center;
        // 
        // txtUsuario
        // 
        this->txtUsuario->AccessibleDescription = L"USUARIO";
        this->txtUsuario->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Times New Roman", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->txtUsuario->Location = System::Drawing::Point(212, 298);
        this->txtUsuario->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this->txtUsuario->Name = L"txtUsuario";
        this->txtUsuario->Size = System::Drawing::Size(424, 49);
        this->txtUsuario->TabIndex = 4;
        this->txtUsuario->Text = L"USUARIO";
        this->txtUsuario->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Center;
        // 
        // loginAdmi
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(9, 20);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(803, 708);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->btnAceptar);
        this->Controls->Add(this->txtPassw);
        this->Controls->Add(this->txtUsuario);
        this->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this->Name = L"loginAdmi";
        this->Text = L"loginAdmi";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
void MarshalString(String ^ s, string& os) {
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars =
        (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

private: System::Void btnAceptar_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String ^ user = txtUsuario->Text; //obtiene el dato del textbox
    String ^passw = txtPassw->Text; //obtiene el dato del textbox txtUsuario->Text;
    string userS;
    string passwS;
    MarshalString(user, userS);
    MarshalString(passw, passwS);
    bool logeado = false;
    if(AdministradorS::socket.puertoS ==5400)    //socket deberia ser la variable con el objeto entrante seteado 
        MessageBox::Show("5400");
    else if(AdministradorS::socket.puertoS == 5500)   //socket deberia ser la variable con el objeto entrante seteado 
        MessageBox::Show("5500");




    /*if (passwS == "1") {
        clienteLOG.enviarporSocketsLOG(logeado, userS, passwS);
        if (logeado == true) {
            this->Hide();
            AdministradorMenu::administrador menuP;
            menuP.ShowDialog();
        }
    }*/
}
private: System::Void loginAdmi_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
};
}
```

Mi duda en forma general es como crear una variable en el código de la interfaz que pueda setear el objeto entrante y así ser usado en la acción del botón? (no puedo crear variables de forma normal ya que ocurre un error de que la variable ya fue creada imagino que por los hilos)
de antemano gracias y espero haberme expresado bien en mi pregunta, disculpen si el código tiene mucha sección comentada o así soy nuevo.

Comment: Hola Paula claro voy a hacerlo dame un momento

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Tu duda es "*crear una variable en el código de la interfaz*". De entre todo el código que has compartido ¿Qué es la interfaz y dónde quieres añadir variables y de qué tipo deben ser?